# Conditionally remove row with multiple reference

Tags: r

I would like to remove the entire row itself and above if that column has "ClearPrevious". However I have problem with multiple-sequential "ClearPrevious" that made things a little complicated.

Input:

```
 tmp <- data.frame(V1 = c("event1", "ClearPrevious", "event2", "event3", "event4", "ClearPrevious", "ClearPrevious", "event5"))
```

My output:

```
1 event2
2 event3
3 event5
```

Desired output:

```
1 event2
2 event5
```

My unsuccessful-attempt code:

```
row_delete <- c(which(tmp$V1 == "ClearPrevious"))
row_to_be_deleted <- c(row_delete-1)
View(tmp[-c(row_to_be_deleted, row_delete),])
```

Comment: Can you explain what's the logic? Why don't keep `event3`?

Comment: because an event could be recorded as mistake/error.

Comment: are you okay with looping? I am thinking for iteration as long as 'ClearPrevious' is there

Answer (score 2):

This is what i tried:

```
rm(list=ls())
tmp <- data.frame(V1 = c("event1", "ClearPrevious", "event2", "event3", 
                         "event4", "ClearPrevious", "ClearPrevious", "event5"),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)

while(any(grep('ClearPrevious', tmp$V1)))
{
  clearindex <- which(tmp$V1 == 'ClearPrevious')
  event_index <- grep('event', tmp$V1)
  toremove <- intersect(clearindex-1, event_index)

  V1 <- tmp[-c(toremove, toremove+1),]
  tmp <- as.data.frame(V1)

}
tmp
# event2
# event5
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this:

```
mutate(tmp,m=`length<-`(V1[-1],nrow(tmp)))%>%
     with(V1[(!m=="ClearPrevious"|is.na(m))&!V1=="ClearPrevious"])
[1] event2 event3 event5

fun=function(s) {
  while(any(grepl("ClearPrevious",s)))
    s=trimws(gsub("\\w+\\s+ClearPrevious","",paste(s,collapse = " ")))
  strsplit(s,"\\s+")[[1]]
}
fun(tmp$V1)
[1] "event2" "event5"
```